# Word for behavior change when a superior is around?

Tags: behavior

People (especially in groups) act differently when they are aware that a superior is present. I am looking for a term that describes this phenomenon.

Similar but not quite what I mean:

- The [Hawthorne effekt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawthorne-Effekt) describes behavior change when people are aware that they are part of a study.
- The [John Henry effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Henry_effect) describes behavior change when people are aware that they are part of a study and in the controll group.
- The [watching eye effekt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watching-eye_effect) describes behavior change when people feel watched (but doesn't take hierarchy into account, even drawn eyes work).